In SVD Decomposition of X, X= USV^T, what is the relation between U columns to PCA?
On several websites, I've seen contradictory perspectives that led me to believe the columns of U are the principal component vectors (U_j = PC_j), but on others like
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/195385/what-is-the-principal-components-matrix-in-pca-with-svd 
It proves that the columns of V are the eigenvectors. When I did the calculation myself I got that U_j = PC_j. If it's wrong, can someone please explain to me the relation between U and the PC vectors?
